# Quasar VueJS app with Cordova loads application on iOS simulator with blank page only

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to deploy an iOS app from VueJS Quasar framework using Cordova. When I load the application on the dev environment ( with quasar dev ), it runs the application through a browser and works fine.

However when I "export" to cordova project on iOS platform, in xCode I get the following error in the console: "`Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server`" and the simulator loads an empty white blank page only.

The app has been built and tried on an iPhone as well, and it's the same reason: empty blank page.

We are using API in the background from another server as well, where we have set the CORS to allow *.

Note: exported to android platform it works nice.

Did anybody have this problem, and knows what the solution is? Thanks!